# How can I set a daily limit on a specific user's login time?

Tags: command-line, scripts, login, user-management, quota

I need to restrict the use of a machine to two hours per day (total, across multiple sessions of being physically logged in at the console). Is there any way I can do that?

Edit: I suppose I could do something with `pam_exec`, but before I go that route and accidentally lock myself out of my machine (like I did with my Pi :( )....